# Reduce filesize of plotly html files

Tags: python, plotly, plotly.js

When exporting a graph to html using plotly, filesize can become quite big.
For example using the code below I end up with a ~30MB html file.
I know that by using the `include_plotlyjs="cdn"` option I can spare ~3MB but will need a internet connection to actually see the plot.

Is there a way of compressing the data inside the html file and still be able to open it on the fly?

By e.g. using 7zip I can compress the ~30MB html file to a ~8MB archive. But in order to open this I will have to extract it first.

```
#large file example (results in a ~30MB html file)
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# some input data
x = np.arange(0, 1e6)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = px.line(x=x,y=y)
fig.write_html("myLargePlot.html") 
fig.write_html("myLargePlot_NoPlotlyJs.html", include_plotlyjs="cdn") # ~3 MB smaller file
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a compression, but you can already try to minify the HTML file.
This is the suppression of all useless character (mostly spaces and line break) in a file that are not required for interpreting it.

In python, you can use the `htmlmin` module:

```
pip install htmlmin
```

```py
import htmlmin
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# some input data
x = np.arange(0, 1e6)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = px.line(x=x,y=y)
fig.write_html("myLargePlot.html") 
fig.write_html("myLargePlot_NoPlotlyJs.html", include_plotlyjs="cdn")

file = open("myLargePlot_NoPlotlyJs.html", "r")
html_contents = file.read()
file.close()

html_minified = htmlmin.minify(html_contents, remove_empty_space=True)
file = open("minified_file.html", "w")
file.write(html_minified)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, unfortunately this removes only a few bytes:
Original: 28 532 722 Bytes; 
Minified: 28 532 628 Bytes